# Day date JS additional

Tags: javascript, html

Here is my JS which will show current day date and month.

Example (month/day): `08/01/2015`:

```
http://www.domain.com/0801
```

The problem is there is no zero infront of them and become like:

```
http://www.domain.com/81
```

How to add `0` infront of them so will become `0801`

Here is the code

```
    var currentTime = new Date();
    var month = currentTime.getMonth() + 1
    var day = currentTime.getDate();
    var year = currentTime.getFullYear();
```

Comment: What about http://www.domain.com/111 how to parse this? is it 01-11 or 11-01

Comment: @MayankPandya it should be month/day = 1101

Comment: It is called padding and is easily found here and elsewhere on the net

Comment: Anyone can help look into this.

Comment: anyone can help solve this. thnks.